# Mass Looped/Bulk Inserts using PHP into ArrangoDB

Tags: arangodb-php

I wish to write batches of 180-250k documents into an ArrangoDB collection using PHP.
It's very easy to add a single document. It's just as easy to throw the insertion of a document into a loop and make 1000's of individual inserts. However surely this is not the most optimised and appropriate way to do batch inserts of 100's of thousands of documents?

What would be the best way to go about doing this in PHP? What tweaks to the set up can be done to boost performance with this kind of requirement? What's the fastest way to write 100k batches of documents into a collection?

Any insights, thoughts, and help would be appreciated!

I'm using PHP 7, ArrangoDB 3.4

Comment: There is batch-insertion support in `arangodb-php`; `ArangoDBClient\Batch` - is this not sufficient for your task?